# which one faster to access one large field or multiple small fields with equal data length?

Tags: database

i am in litle confusion....
Let we have a large field in the database,and same field is splitted in the other table.
eg address(containing all city state ,country) in table1...
and add, city,state,country in table2... all are separte column.

i need complete address which on is faster..
Select address from table1    (larger data in one field)
or
Select city,state,country from table 2.. (same data is splitted in these fields)(data length equal in both cases)
plz reply
regards

Answer (score 1):

As long as the separate fields are on the same row, performance differences should be minimal.

If you are designing a new table, I strongly recommend against concatenating different fields into the same database column - for one particular query, you may need to combine them into a single address field, but in other queries you will probably need to handle them separately. It is much harder to split a single field into multiple fields, than it is to join multiple fields into a single field. (Having multiple values in a single field is also a violation of first normal form.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (just maybe) large field is faster.

But i have a very big question mark here. Why would you do such a thing?